# Filter an array via javascript

Tags: javascript

Good day.

I made a form with inputs with HTML and CSS. Via javascript i put the input data in an array, but now i want to filter in that array.That filter should show me all the input data of the people that ask for one of these destinies. Canarias, Mallorca,Galicia.

```js
let arrViaje = [];

function recoger() {
  let nombre = document.getElementById("name").value
  let origen = document.getElementById("origin").value
  let destino = document.getElementById("destiny").value
  let personas = document.getElementById("people").value
  let fechas = document.getElementById("dates").value

  let viaje = {
    name: nombre,
    origin: origen,
    destiny: destino,
    people: personas,
    dates: fechas
  }
  console.log(viaje)

  arrViaje.push(viaje);
  console.log(arrViaje)
}

function filtrar() {
  let ciudadSinFiltrar = "Canarias"
  let ciudad = ciudadSinFiltrar.toLowerCase
  let filteredArray = arrViaje.filter((city) => city.filter(ciudad))
  console.log(filteredArray)
}
```

```html
<div class="formulario">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" class="datos" id="name" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="text" class="datos" id="origin" placeholder="Origen">
    <input type="text" class="datos" id="destiny" placeholder="Destino">
    <input type="text" class="datos" id="people" placeholder="Personas">
    <input type="text" class="datos" id="dates" placeholder="Fecha">
  </form>
  <button onclick="recoger()">Mas información</button>
  <button onclick="filtrar()">Filtrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your current code not meeting your expectations?  Do you just need to `return filteredArray;` in `filtarar()`?

Comment: `recoger` is missing a closing tag. That WILL cause syntax error

Comment: you are not using the `toLowerCase()` method correctly here `let ciudad = ciudadSinFiltrar.toLowerCase`

Comment: It's not working. I'm getting this error. Uncaught ReferenceError: filtrar is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. Can't understand why filtrar is a function and is also a button. I defined it twice

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to not only be able to add a trip, but also filter any existing trips, you will need to devise a way to set and grab the form data.

After clicking "Add", you will need to subsequently "Filter" the results based on the form input. You can also "Reset" the form and provide only the fields you want to filter on.

```js
const tripForm = document.forms['trip-form'];
const tripList = document.querySelector('#trip-list');

const allTrips = [];
let filteredTrips = [];

setFormData({
  name: 'Joe',
  origin: 'Toronto',
  destination: 'Canary Islands',
  people: 4,
  startDate: '2024-07-01',
  endDate: '2024-07-05'
});

function addTrip() {
  const trip = {
    name: tripForm.elements.name.value,
    origin: tripForm.elements.origin.value,
    destination: tripForm.elements.destination.value,
    people: tripForm.elements.people.valueAsNumber,
    startDate: tripForm.elements.startDate.value,
    endDate: tripForm.elements.endDate.value
  };
  console.log(trip);
  allTrips.push(trip);
}

function filterTrips() {
  const filters = buildFilters();
    
  filteredTrips = filters.length
    ? allTrips.filter(trip =>  filters.every(({ key, value }) => trip[key] === value))
    : allTrips;
    
  renderFilterdTrips();
}

function renderFilterdTrips() {
  tripList.innerHTML = filteredTrips.map(trip => {
    const { name, origin, destination, people, startDate, endDate } = trip;
    const from = new Date(startDate).toLocaleDateString();
    const to = new Date(endDate).toLocaleDateString();
    return `
      <li>
        ${name} [${origin} -> ${destination}] (${people} people) [${from}-${to}]
      </li>
    `
  }).join('');
}


function setFormData(state) {
  for (let name in state) {
    if (name === undefined) continue; // Skip
    tripForm.elements[name].value = state[name] ?? '';
  }
}

function getFormData() {
  const data = {};
  for (let field of tripForm.elements) {
    if (!field.name || !field.value) continue;
    data[field.name] = getValueForField(field)
  }
  return data;
}

function getValueForField(input) {
  switch (input.type) {
    case 'number': return input.valueAsNumber;
    case 'date': // new Date(input.value);
    case 'text':
    default: return input.value;
  }
}

function buildFilters() {
  return Object.entries(getFormData())
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));
}
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form name="trip-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" name="origin" placeholder="Origin">
    <input type="text" name="destination" placeholder="Destination">
    <input type="number" name="people" placeholder="People">
    <input type="date" name="startDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="date" name="endDate" placeholder="Date">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addTrip()">Add</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="filterTrips()">Filter</button>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <ul id="trip-list"></ul>
</div>
```